# AngularJs promise not updating shared Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm not sure why this customer data doesn't update the shoppingCart.html template, this function is part of a shared model class returned by a factory.

the $http is injected but the model class can't manage to update itself inside the promise result.
So the template is finally updated.
What would be the best way to do that?

http://plnkr.co/edit/ro6FTa5AbhnzrMsnWIyi?p=preview

```
    shoppingCart.prototype.fillCustomerInformation = function()
    {
        var customerDeferred = this.$q.defer();
        var customerApi = customerDeferred.promise;

        this.$http.get('/customer.json').then(function (result) {
            customerDeferred.resolve(result.data);
            console.log(result.data);
            this.customer.firstName = result.data.firstName;
            this.saveItems()
        });

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `this` refers to the success ajax handler. You can do this:

```
shoppingCart.prototype.fillCustomerInformation = function()
    {
        var customerDeferred = this.$q.defer();
        var customerApi = customerDeferred.promise;
        var that = this;

        this.$http.get('/customer.json').then(function (result) {
            customerDeferred.resolve(result.data);
            console.log(result.data);
            that.customer.firstName = result.data.firstName;
            that.saveItems()
        });

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for a start you have `firstName` spelt wrong in `result.data.firtName` instead of `result.data.firstName`

Secondly there are many ways to bind service members to scope variables but what i found was the best way of doing that is to do stuff like

```
$scope.$watch(
  function () {
    return DataService.cart;
  },
  function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // do your stuff to manage updates here
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks, ok I updated the typo and I'll check for the alternative way , but the question is why inside the then method the customer property is not updated for the model class and neither propagated to the view